# Histograma back to back en r

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo algunos problemas con mi script de R. Intento llevar a cabo un histograma comparativo con la función `hist back to back`, pero al intentar cambiar `xlim` con porcentajes (del 0 al 1) y reducir los breaks (tamaño de las barras) el gráfico me muestra una imagen carente de sentido.

Por lo tanto, no sé cómo agregar porcentajes en el eje x (por ejemplo, 0.2...,0.6...) y reducir el tamaño de las bars.

Mi script es:

```
histbackback(bbdd$var1, bbdd$var2, main="", xlab=c("", ""), ylab="", probability = T)

barplot(-figure1$left, col="blue", horiz = TRUE, space=0, add=TRUE, axes= FALSE)
abline(v=c(-0.04,-0.02), lwd=2, lty=3, col= "dark blue")

barplot(figure1$right, col="green", horiz = TRUE, space=0, add=TRUE, axes= FALSE)
abline(v=c(0.04,0.02), lwd=2, lty=3, col= "dark blue")
```

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda,
Un cordial saludo,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ajustar los `bins` del histograma, en el caso de `histbackback` lo puedes configurar con el parámetro `brks`, dónde le pasas según dice la ayuda:

> vector of the desired breakpoints for the histograms.

Por ejemplo:

```
library("Hmisc")
options(digits=3)

set.seed(2020)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
histbackback(x, y)
```

Obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O bien, ajustamos los cortes del histogramna generando un vector con mayor resolución:

```
histbackback(x, y, brks = seq(from=-4,to=4,by=.1))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O si quieres definir directamente el número de barras que quieres:

```
bins <- 50
mx <- max(c(x,y)) + .5
mi <- min(c(x,y)) - .5
brks <- seq(from=mi,to=mx,length.out=bins)
```